# Encoding special characters whilst setting parameters on the URL

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode, urlsearchparams

I need to set a number of URL parameters, which also need to include a special character `$`

Currently I am using `.set()` to create and set these parameter values:

```
const myUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/?");

let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('$param1', '60');
params.set('$param2', '100');
```

I understand that I need to use `encodeURI()` to ensure that I get `$` in the URL and not `%24` - but at what stage do I do this?

If I do this when I stringify and add the params to the URL they have already been converted.

```
myUrl.search = encodeURI(params.toString());
// Outputs: http://www.example.com/?%24param1=60&%24param2=100
// Desired: http://www.example.com/?$param1=60&$param2=100
```

Comment: Why would you want to have the `$` which is not a valid URL entity?

Comment: @mplungjan because that is the requirement for what I need to do

Comment: Then it has been answered

Comment: If you want to build an invalid URL, just build it as a string; that's all it is anyway.

Comment: @Pointy that was my initial solution but as I need to add a lot of params and also add some logic around what to include, using a long template string became quite confusing and hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `$` character is being encoded as `%24` because it's a reserved character in URLs. The `URLSearchParams` object's `set` method automatically encodes these characters to ensure the resulting string is a valid URL.

However, if you want to include the `$` character as is, you can bypass the automatic encoding by manually constructing the query string:

```js
const myUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/?");

let params = ['$param1=60', '$param2=100'].join('&');

myUrl.search = params;

console.log(myUrl.toString());
// Outputs: http://www.example.com/?$param1=60&$param2=100
```

This will give you the desired output, but be aware that this might not be a valid URL according to the URL specification, as `$` is a reserved character. This could potentially lead to issues with some servers or APIs.

If you control the server or API you're interacting with and you're sure it can handle URLs with `$` characters in the query string, then this approach should work. Otherwise, it's generally safer to stick with the automatic encoding provided by `URLSearchParams`.

Please confirm if this solution works for you or if you need further assistance.

Comment: Excellent thank you. Can confirm it is needed in this situation and the server I am interacting with accepts it (and requires it)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need it and your server supports it, just fix it at the end

```js
const myUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/?");

let params = myUrl.searchParams;
params.set('$param1', '60');
params.set('$param2', '100');

console.log(myUrl.toString().replace(/%24/g,"$"))
```